# Symfony Propel Nested Set

Tags: symfony1, propel, nested-sets

I get the tree in symfony with propel with this way:

$tree = FoldersQuery::create()->findTree();

Now, how to list the tree with each child properly?
I want parents be on a specific div, children on an another div and list them. But how?
How to get the relationships between each item and know how to render it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this documentation http://www.propelorm.org/behaviors/nested-set.

You can get all children with `getChildren()`, know whether it's a root node or not with `isRoot()`, know the level, ...
See more on the API section, it will help you :)